# Android XML alignment issue with Linear and RelativeLayouts.

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to design this layout in Android XML

[image]

i wrote the xml and works fine without putting "TEXT VIEW 2" code.

This is my XML file without putting TEXT VIEW 2 :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"

    >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    >

    <!-- This is TEXTVIEW 1 -->
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW1"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />

    <ImageView     
    android:id="@+id/list_image"   
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
    />

</RelativeLayout>

    <!-- WebView  -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        > 

        <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    />

    </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone plz suggest me where should i put TEXTVIEW2 code which works like my given graphical layout image.

Code for TEXTVIEW 2 is same as TEXTVIEW 1:-

```
<!-- This is TEXTVIEW 2 -->
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW2"
            android:text="ITEM"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"

        />
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>
<!-- This is TEXTVIEW 1 -->
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW1"
    android:text="ITEM"

    android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"

/>

<!-- This is TEXTVIEW 2 -->
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW2"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it after `TEXTVIEW1` with additional property as

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TEXTVIEW1"
```

---

Also, there is no need to put `WebView` in separate `LinearLayout`.
Just add  following in `WebView` declaration:

```
android:layout_below="@id/list_image"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it anywhere in your code, RelativeLayout lays elements out based on their paramters, not the order they are listed in. If it's not displaying correctly it's because of your android: parameters, in this case the fact that it has the exact same parameters as TextView1 means Android will dump it on top of TextView1 - RelativeLayout stacks views on top of each other if they are put into the same spot.

To get it under TextView1, you should use the following:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW2"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TEXTVIEW1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TEXTVIEW1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

It could seem like you've misunderstood the concept of the `RelativeLayout` - to avoid unnecessary nesting of `ViewGroup`s.

I'd suggest something like this (pseudo-XML):

```
RelativeLayout ->
  ImageView (aligned to top-left corner, with some padding)
  TextView (aligned to right of ImageView and to top, with padding)
  TextView (aligned to right of ImageView and to bottom of previous TextView, with padding)
  WebView (aligned to bottom of ImageView)
```

See? The point is, that when you use a `RelativeLayout` as the root element, you don't need to have a lot of nested `ViewGroup`s (like `LinearLayout`) inside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Textview 2

```
android:layout_above="textView 1"
android:layout_alignRight="image view"
```